# python range from data frame to generate extra rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, numpy

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: mapping table]

How can I convert it to:

```
ID  mapping_value   RANGE    
10  A   001
10  A   002
10  A   003
10  A   004
10  A   212
20  C   001
20  C   002
20  C   003
20  C   004
20  C   005
20  C   006
20  C   007
```

this is in order to make a relationship database easier to join on afterwards

Comment: could you add the code instead of the picture? pictures normally don't do well here on SO

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit hard to understand , but it will achieve what you need

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[10,20],'map':['A','C'],'Range':['001:004,212','001:007']})

df.Range=df.Range.str.split(',')
a=df.set_index(['ID','map']).Range.apply(pd.Series).stack()

yourdf=a.str.split(':').apply(pd.Series).ffill(1).\
   apply(lambda x : [np.arange(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)],1)[0].\
       apply(pd.Series).stack().\
          reset_index(level=[2,3],drop=True).reset_index() 

yourdf
Out[756]: 
    ID map      0
0   10   A    1.0
1   10   A    2.0
2   10   A    3.0
3   10   A    4.0
4   10   A  212.0
5   20   C    1.0
6   20   C    2.0
7   20   C    3.0
8   20   C    4.0
9   20   C    5.0
10  20   C    6.0
11  20   C    7.0
```

Comment: It seems to me whatever is going on here would almost certainly be better to implement in vanilla python

Answer (score 0):

Some vanilla python approach:

```
odf = pd.DataFrame([{'ID':'10', 'range':'001:004,212','mapping_value':'A'},
                    {'ID':'20', 'range':'001:007','mapping_value':'C'}])

df_input = []

def expand_range(i_range):
    lower, upper = i_range.split(':')
    return [str(e).zfill(3) for e in range(int(lower), int(upper)+1)]

for r in odf.itertuples():
    for rg in [element for sublist in
               [expand_range(e) if ':' in e else [e] for e in r.range.split(',')]
               for element in sublist]:
        df_input.append({'ID':r.ID,'mapping_value':r.mapping_value,'range':rg})

df = pd.DataFrame(df_input)
```

This gives:

```
    ID mapping_value range
0   10             A   001
1   10             A   002
2   10             A   003
3   10             A   004
4   10             A   212
5   20             C   001
6   20             C   002
7   20             C   003
8   20             C   004
9   20             C   005
10  20             C   006
11  20             C   007
```

Edit:
Switched from iterrows() to itertuples() as it is supposed to be a bit faster, supports nice dot-notation by returning namedtuples and apparently preserves dtypes